# "Extract text within div tag" but gives error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's a piece of code I would like to extract the text "`Available at Amazon starting at $200"`.Here's what I've written so far

```
import re
Cost_List = []
for result in stroller_result:
    if result.find('div', class_ = 'product__retailer__text') is not None:
        Cost = result.find_all('div', {'class': ["product__retailer__text", re.compile(r'\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?')]})
    Cost_List.append(Cost)
```

This code returns this:

```
[[<div class="product__retailer__text">Available at Amazon starting at $200</div>],
 [<div class="product__retailer__text">Available at Amazon starting at $200</div>],
 [<div class="product__retailer__text">Available at Amazon starting at $500</div>],
 [<div class="product__retailer__text">Available at Amazon starting at $100</div>],
 [<div class="product__retailer__text">Available at Amazon starting at $100</div>],
```

If I try to extract the text I do get this error:
`'Available at Amazon starting at $200' using .text I get the following error - AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

```
import re
Cost_List = []
for result in stroller_result:
    if result.find('div', class_ = 'product__retailer__text') is not None:
        Cost = result.find_all('div', {'class': ["product__retailer__text", re.compile(r'\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?')]}).text
    Cost_List.append(Cost)
```

Comment: What's your question? Like the error says, you cannot call .text on a list of items.

Comment: ok im new to webscraping didnt know that. My goal is to just extract the text

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of your error, you can call `.text` on each element, rather than on the list of elements.

```
import re
Cost_List = []
for result in stroller_result:
    if result.find('div', class_ = 'product__retailer__text') is not None:
        Cost = result.find_all('div', {'class': ["product__retailer__text", re.compile(r'\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?')]})
        Cost = [el.text for el in Cost]
        Cost_List.append(Cost)
```

Comment: I get the following error when i tried that.   AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: I've updated the answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked :

```
import re
Cost_List = []
for result in stroller_result:
    if result.find('div', class_ = 'product__retailer__text') is not None:
        Cost = [x.text for x in result.find_all('div', {'class': ["product__retailer__text", re.compile(r'\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?')]})]
    Cost_List.append(Cost)
```

Comment: This will fail however if result.find() returns None. It will then append Cost from the previous iteration.